# Derivative of abs(x'Ax) with respect to x

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I would like to know how the derivative of  $ f=\mathrm{abs}(x^\top \cdot A\cdot x)
$ is derived, where $x$ is a vector and $A$ is a matrix.

Following the chain rule I would have expected it to be

$
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -\mathrm{sign}(x^\top \cdot A\cdot x)(A \cdot x+A^\top \cdot x)
$

However according to http://www.matrixcalculus.org/, the derivative is

$
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \mathrm{sign}(x^\top \cdot A\cdot x)\cdot A\cdot x+\mathrm{sign}(x^\top \cdot A^\top \cdot x)\cdot A^\top \cdot x
$

How is this derived? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The quantity $(x^TAx)$ is a _real_ scalar and therefore equal to its own transpose, but the website failed to take this equality into account. Otherwise it would have returned your result.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course. Thank you so much.